# How to avoid jsession id from URL in Liferay Portal?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Please can anyone tell me how can i get rid of `JSESSIONID` parameter from URL?
I do not want it to be appended to the URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the portal-ext.properties file set:

`session.enable.url.with.session.id=false`