# Remove Jsessionid from url with liferay 6

Tags: java, jboss, liferay, jsessionid, server-administration

I am having problems with the ;jsessionid=xxx in the URLs coming from Liferay. I want to use *only* cookies. I finde this parametar (session.enable.url.with.session.id=false) but also i don t know where put this parametar
I am using Liferay 6.0.12 (SP2) with the bundled jboss

Comment: This is rather on the appserver side - you'll have to check how to configure jboss to use cookies, and it might fall back to URLs if it determines that the browser doesn't accept cookies. As the question is not programming related (rather server administration) I'm suggesting to move it off of stackoverflow.

Comment: In `portal-ext.properties` [How to avoid jsession id from URL in Liferay Portal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512426/how-to-avoid-jsession-id-from-url-in-liferay-portal)